# How to solve IndexError in Django 1.8.6

Tags: django

I am getting list index out of range error in my application. It is an e-learning system and the error occurs when a student tries to enroll in for a course. I am using django 1.8.6. This is my error.

```
IndexError at /students/course/12/
list index out of range
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/students/course/12/
    Django Version: 1.8.6
    Exception Type: IndexError
    Exception Value: list index out of range
    Exception Location: D:\DjangoSchoolProject\env\educa\lib\site- 
    packages\django\db\models\query.py in __getitem__, line 201
    Python Executable:  D:\DjangoSchoolProject\env\educa\Scripts\python.exe
    Python Version: 3.6.5
    Python Path:    
              ['D:\\DjangoSchoolProject\\educa',
              'D:\\DjangoSchoolProject\\env\\educa\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
              'D:\\DjangoSchoolProject\\env\\educa\\DLLs',
              'D:\\DjangoSchoolProject\\env\\educa\\lib',
              'D:\\DjangoSchoolProject\\env\\educa\\Scripts',           
          'c:\\users\\greendelta\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36- 
              32\\Lib',
          'c:\\users\\greendelta\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36- 
               32\\DLLs',
              'D:\\DjangoSchoolProject\\env\\educa',
               'D:\\DjangoSchoolProject\\env\\educa\\lib\\site-packages']
```

and this is the python file I am using to enroll student.
from django import forms
from courses.models import Course

```
class CourseEnrollForm(forms.Form):
    course = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Course.objects.all(),
                                widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I have also included my view.py file below

Here is my view.py file.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateResponseMixin, View
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.forms.models import modelform_factory
from django.db.models import Count
from django.apps import apps
from django.core.cache import cache
 from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, \
                     CsrfExemptMixin, JsonRequestResponseMixin
from students.forms import CourseEnrollForm
from .models import Subject, Course, Module, Content
from .forms import ModuleFormSet


class OwnerMixin(object):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(OwnerMixin, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(owner=self.request.user)


class OwnerEditMixin(object):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        return super(OwnerEditMixin, self).form_valid(form)


 class OwnerCourseMixin(OwnerMixin, LoginRequiredMixin):
     model = Course


 class OwnerCourseEditMixin(OwnerCourseMixin, OwnerEditMixin):
     fields = ['subject', 'title', 'slug', 'overview']
     success_url = reverse_lazy('manage_course_list')
     template_name = 'courses/manage/course/form.html'


 class ManageCourseListView(OwnerCourseMixin, ListView):
     template_name = 'courses/manage/course/list.html'


 class CourseCreateView(PermissionRequiredMixin,
                   OwnerCourseEditMixin,
                   CreateView):
    permission_required = 'courses.add_course'


class CourseUpdateView(PermissionRequiredMixin,
                   OwnerCourseEditMixin,
                   UpdateView):
    permission_required = 'courses.change_course'


class CourseDeleteView(PermissionRequiredMixin,
                   OwnerCourseMixin,
                   DeleteView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy('manage_course_list')
    template_name = 'courses/manage/course/delete.html'
    permission_required = 'courses.delete_course'


class CourseModuleUpdateView(TemplateResponseMixin, View):
    template_name = 'courses/manage/module/formset.html'
    course = None

    def get_formset(self, data=None):
        return ModuleFormSet(instance=self.course,
                         data=data)

    def dispatch(self, request, pk):
        self.course = get_object_or_404(Course, id=pk, owner=request.user)
        return super(CourseModuleUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, pk)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         formset = self.get_formset()
        return self.render_to_response({'course': self.course,
                                    'formset': formset})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         formset = self.get_formset(data=request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return redirect('manage_course_list')
        return self.render_to_response({'course': self.course,
                                    'formset': formset})


class ContentCreateUpdateView(TemplateResponseMixin, View):
     module = None
     model = None
      obj = None
    template_name = 'courses/manage/content/form.html'

    def get_model(self, model_name):
        if model_name in ['text', 'video', 'image', 'file']:
            return apps.get_model(app_label='courses', model_name=model_name)
        return None

    def get_form(self, model, *args, **kwargs):
         Form = modelform_factory(model,
                             exclude=['owner', 'order', 'created', 'updated'])
        return Form(*args, **kwargs)

    def dispatch(self, request, module_id, model_name, id=None):
        self.module = get_object_or_404(Module,
                                    id=module_id,
                                    course__owner=request.user)
        self.model = self.get_model(model_name)
        if id:
            self.obj = get_object_or_404(self.model,
                                     id=id,
                                     owner=request.user)
        return super(ContentCreateUpdateView,
                 self).dispatch(request, module_id, model_name, id)

    def get(self, request, module_id, model_name, id=None):
        form = self.get_form(self.model, instance=self.obj)
        return self.render_to_response({'form': form,
                                    'object': self.obj})

    def post(self, request, module_id, model_name, id=None):
        form = self.get_form(self.model,
                         instance=self.obj,
                         data=request.POST,
                         files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.owner = request.user
            obj.save()
            if not id:
                # new content
                Content.objects.create(module=self.module,
                                   item=obj)
            return redirect('module_content_list', self.module.id)

        return self.render_to_response({'form': form,
                                    'object': self.obj})


class ContentDeleteView(View):

    def post(self, request, id):
        content = get_object_or_404(Content,
                                id=id,
                                module__course__owner=request.user)
        module = content.module
        content.item.delete()
        content.delete()
        return redirect('module_content_list', module.id)


class ModuleContentListView(TemplateResponseMixin, View):
    template_name = 'courses/manage/module/content_list.html'

    def get(self, request, module_id):
        module = get_object_or_404(Module,
                               id=module_id,
                               course__owner=request.user)

        return self.render_to_response({'module': module})


class ModuleOrderView(CsrfExemptMixin, JsonRequestResponseMixin, View):

    def post(self, request):
        for id, order in self.request_json.items():
            Module.objects.filter(id=id,
                              course__owner=request.user).update(order=order)
        return self.render_json_response({'saved': 'OK'})


 class ContentOrderView(CsrfExemptMixin, JsonRequestResponseMixin, View):

    def post(self, request):
        for id, order in self.request_json.items():
            Content.objects.filter(id=id,

module__course__owner=request.user).update(order=order)
        return self.render_json_response({'saved': 'OK'})


 class CourseListView(TemplateResponseMixin, View):
      model = Course
      template_name = 'courses/course/list.html'

     def get(self, request, subject=None):
         subjects = cache.get('all_subjects')
         if not subjects:
             subjects = Subject.objects.annotate(total_courses=Count('courses'))
             cache.set('all_subjects', subjects)
         all_courses = Course.objects.annotate(total_modules=Count('modules'))
        if subject:
            subject = get_object_or_404(Subject, slug=subject)
            key = 'subject_{}_courses'.format(subject.id)
            courses = cache.get(key)
            if not courses:
                courses = all_courses.filter(subject=subject)
                cache.set(key, courses)
        else:
            courses = cache.get('all_courses')
             if not courses:
                 courses = all_courses
                 cache.set('all_courses', courses)
        return self.render_to_response({'subjects': subjects,
                                    'subject': subject,
                                    'courses': courses})


 class CourseDetailView(DetailView):
     model = Course
     template_name = 'courses/course/detail.html'

     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CourseDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['enroll_form'] = CourseEnrollForm(initial={'course':self.object})
        return context
```

I still do not have a working solution to my problem.

Comment: If you could post the view as well that would help. It seems you are referencing an index in a queryset where the queryset is most likely coming back empty.

Comment: Post your view code

Answer (score 0):

Kinda hard give any good answer without the entire code, **please post your view.py thats render your page**

This usualy happends when your try to access array with fixed position without checking if this exists or have this currently position

```
someArray = [1,2,3]    
print(someArray[200])
```

Probabily you trying to acess your queryset or any array with wrong position